# Cannot install a new clickhouse-server. Installation fails with Poco::Exception. Code: 1000

Tags: clickhouse

I am installing clickhouse-server and clickhouse-client locally on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
I had a previous installation that worked fine, but at some point it was broken.
After running officially recommended script from here:
https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/getting-started/install/

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E0C56BD4

echo "deb https://repo.clickhouse.tech/deb/stable/ main/" | sudo tee \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y clickhouse-server clickhouse-client

sudo service clickhouse-server start
clickhouse-client
```

I received the error:

```
Users config file /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml already exists, will keep it and extract users info from it.
Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Exception: Failed to merge config with '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml': SAXParseException: Invalid token in '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml', line 1 column 13 (version 21.1.2.15 (official build))
dpkg: error processing package clickhouse-server (--configure):
 installed clickhouse-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 232
Setting up clickhouse-client (21.1.2.15) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clickhouse-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There was a prompt to insert a password, but I ignored it and just pressed Enter. What is the best way to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show `cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml` ?
it should have empty password if you pressed `enter`.

And you can remove `rm /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml`

Comment: Thanks, it helped.